# Matlab: Function to check for negative values

Tags: function, matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

Is there a built-in matlab function that checks if a value is negative?

For example,

```
x = -4; % For neg

isneg(x) = 1;

y = 3; % For pos

isneg(y) = 0;
```

Comment: How about `@(x) x < 0`?

Comment: please explain more specifically, sorry I am beginner.

Comment: How about [sign](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sign.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You can create [*anonymous function*](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) like :

```
>> fun = @(val) val < 0 ;
>> fun(-4)

ans =

     1

>> fun(3)

ans =

     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go:

```
function answer = isneg(value)
    if value < 0
        answer = 1;
    else
        answer = 0;
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should think of the **properties of a negative number**. Once you have done that, you can easily check if a number is negative or not. I can think of a few ways of doing this.

**Negative numbers have imaginary square roots**. Thus, taking the square root of `-x` and checking if it's real is a simple way of doing this. Check out [`isreal`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/isreal.html).

```
neg = isreal(sqrt(-x));
```

If you try **`sin(x)` of a negative number, you will get a negative answer between 0 and -1**. If you use the function [`floor`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/floor.html) and return the negative value of this you will have your answer (note, this will fail if your number happens to be exactly `pi/2`).

```
neg = -floor(sin(x));
```

Of course, **dividing by zero will give you infinite**. Since `x + abs(x) == 0` for negative numbers only, a simple way to check for negative values is to divide `1` by `x + abs(x)`, and use [`isinf`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/isinf.html) this way:

```
neg = isinf(1/(x + abs(x)));
```

Now, using the operation `logical not`, you can check if **the absolute value is unequal to the value itself**, this way:

```
neg = (x ~= abs(x));
```

However, you *could* also check out [`sign`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sign.html). It will return `1` if the sign is positive and `0` if the number is negative. Thus you have two alternatives:

```
neg = sign(-x);
```

or

```
neg = 1 - sign(x);
```

Comment: +Inf^0 for dividing by zero.